# When I activate fractional scaling and go into any fullscreen my screen starts to flicker

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors

When I activate fractional scaling and go into any fullscreen (doesn't matter if it's in the browser or VLC or anything) my screen blacks out and starts to flicker around. If I turn it off, everything works just fine. The problem is I have a 4k display and a full hd display and 200% percent scaling is way too big for me so I can't just turn it off. I don't know if this matters but I have an Nvidia GPU though the drivers should be up to date.